# How to add custom mime type in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I have a special service to upload files. When upload is finished, I send a broadcast from my service - which contains a special serialized object. This object may be an instance of many classes.
To recognize this object class, I use a custom intent type.

How it looks:

```
// Sending broadcast
Intent intent = new Intent(UploaderService.ACTION_UPLOAD_SUCCESSFULLY);
intent.setType(UploaderService.TYPE_DOC);
intent.putExtra(UploaderService.FIELD_RESULT, object);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);

// Registering receiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(UploaderService.ACTION_UPLOAD_SUCCESSFULLY);
filter.addDataType(UploaderService.TYPE_DOC);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

During the registering receiver I catch `IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException`.
`TYPE_DOC` constant looks like `"vnd.com.my.package.doc"`.

So, I suppose, my mime type must be registered in system. How I can do it within code?

Comment: **"vnd.com.my.package.doc"** is a ContentProvider.  Did you register a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, I suppose, my mime type must be registered in system.

No, you need to use a valid MIME type construction. `vnd.com.my.package.doc` is a malformed MIME type. Use `application/vnd.com.my.package.doc` for a vendor-prefixed MIME type.

Note that using MIME types on broadcasts is rather unusual behavior.

Comment: Thank you, now it's works. What alternative you can suggest to recognizing class of object? The server can return several of them, and I should pass them to activity.

Pass type via intent extra?

Comment: @bvitaliyg: "What alternative you can suggest to recognizing class of object?" -- put information about the type in an extra.

Comment: @CommsWare why do you say using MIME types is rather unusual?

Comment: @OladipoOlasemo: I do not recall ever seeing a MIME type used on a broadcast `Intent`. Hence, if it happens at all, it is rather unusual. MIME types are sometimes used for `Intents` used to start activities, but that's about it.