# Get default tap&pay app name

Tags: android, nfc

In my app i use HCE service and i must choose my app in NFC settings tap&pay by default for correct work.
Maybe anyone know how to get default tap&pay application package name programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, use this

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/whatever" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Its not a solution of this problem, what if i have 2 apps on my device vs that intent filters ? you should manually choose in settings which app android must use in contactless tap&pay payments.

Comment: You can define mime type for each app and include this too inside that intent filter. <data android:mimeType="application/whatever" /> For particular mime type, you can set it as default and that will remain as default app

Comment: You can refer this for adding custom mime type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128265/how-to-add-custom-mime-type-in-android

Comment: I am using mastercard SDK and looking for correct usage something like CardEmulation.setPreferredService()